# React hooks: Cannot redirect after redux success action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-hooks

Whenever I try to redirect after an update of `props`, I get this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Tried this already:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.user) {
        props.history.push("/admin/me");
    }
}, [props.user]);
```

And this (Directly in the render method):

```
if (props.user) {
    return <Redirect to="/admin/me" />
}
```

Don't know why redux triggers an update after the component is unmounted. I think that's the problem.

How can I unsubscribe from redux updates before the component is unmounted???

**[EDIT]**

This is the component in question:

```
export interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, RouteComponentProps, React.StatelessComponent, InjectedNotistackProps {
    enqueueSnackbar: (a: any, b: any) => any;
    login: (u: User) => any;
    auth: AuthState;
    api: ApiManager;
};

const LoginPage = (props: Props) => {
    const { classes } = props;

    const api = props.api;
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");


    const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!email || !password) {
            return;
        }

        const user = new User({ email, password });

        props.login(user)
            .then(function success(resp: User) {
                api.setToken(resp.token);
            });
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.auth.user && props.auth.user.token) {
            // return <Redirect to="/profile/me" />  This does not work here...          
            props.history.push("/profile/me");
        }
    }, [props.auth.user]);

    return (
        <main className={classes.main}>
            <CssBaseline />

            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Input onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} name="email" />

                <Input onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} name="password" />

                <Button type="submit">
                    Sign in
                </Button>
            </form>

        </main>
    );
}

const stateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    auth: state.auth || { token: undefined, user: null }
});

const actionToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    login: (user: User): Promise<User> => {

        dispatch(createLoginStartAction("start"));
        return user.login()
            .then(function (loggedInUser: User) {
                    // This seems to be dispatched after the redirect or something!
                    dispatch(createLoginSuccessAction(loggedInUser)); 
                    return loggedInUser;
                });
    }
});

export default connect(stateToProps, actionToProps)(
    withStyles(styles)(
        withSnackbar(LoginPage)
    )
);
```

It turns out that it does redirect, the problem is it goes back to login. Why!?!?

Comment: Please add all relevant code. You probably use the wrong place for your redirects or have some other code that can be triggered `props.user` change or redirect.

Comment: Edited question with a real code sample

Comment: Does `api.setToken` set state on some other component which gets unmounted on redirect?

Comment: it sets a property on an api context object, don't know if that could be the problem. I just tried removing that line and still... Could this happen if the context gets updated from somewhere else?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the wrong component? Do you have other components that are unmounted during this redirect and can in theory set state?

Comment: In deed it was another component. The one I was navigating to :/

Answer (score 0):

This may be an anti-pattern, but I used to get around this issue like this.

In the `constructor` of your class, re-assign the `setState` function like this

```
const originSetState = this.setState.bind(this);
this.setState = ( ...args ) => !this.isUnmounted&&originSetState(...args);
```

Then in `componentWillUnmount` set the boolean to true, preventing `setState` from attempting to update the state:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isUnmounted = true;
}
```

This feels dirty to me, so I've not used it in a while, but it works well for a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I'm using hooks with function components

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix (while also following the conventional React state pattern) is to have the Redirect conditionally render using the component's state. Add a constructor with the state `this.state = {isUser: false}`, and add `{this.state.isUser && <Redirect to="/admin/me" />}` to the bottom of your render method right before `</main>`. Finally change

```
if (props.user) {
    return <Redirect to="/admin/me" />
}
```

to

```
if (props.user) {
    this.setState({isUser: true);
}
```

The result of this follows the conventional React pattern, and when the state changes to true, it'll automatically redirect without performing a no-op!